# conditions for Differentiability at a point of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

First let assume we got the following function:
$$f:{\bf R}^{n}\longrightarrow {\bf R}^{m}$$
Leaving the formal definition of differentiability at a point away, I trying to find out more practical conditions for differentiability at a point of multivariable function.

One of those practical theorems is that if the partial derivatives of the the function are continuous at all points, then the function is differentiable.

Now, I trying to understand if there are conditions for differentiability at a particular point **(assume the point $\vec a$)**, in more precise, **my question is that if it's true to say that if the partial derivatives are continuous in small neighborhood of $\vec a$ then the function is differentiable at the point?**

> if it is not true: does it matter if $m>1$ or not? And moreover, does "practical" theorem of conditions differentiability at a point is exist?

I was trying to find out whether this statement is true or not, without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true ! The corresponding theorem and a proof can be found in

Mathematical Analysis, by Tom M. Apostol, Theorem 6-18.